# Excel 2016: How can I use check boxes and option buttons in formulas?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I'm trying to create a base to use for some simple calculations in excel. I'm not a professional user so my coding skills are very limited. Here is a couple of questions:

1) I have some tables, where it would be cool to have a feature to check boxes for values I use in calculations. However, I have problems using check boxes and option buttons in formulas. Is there any clever way to do this? For an example, I use check boxes and option buttons to pick a value and use that value later on in formula to summarize it with other values.

2) How do I group option buttons to separate questions? I have several questions which require option buttons, but now it acts like I had only one choice between all of my questions.

Thanks.

Comment: Use the frame control to group option buttons into sets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Most controls like checkboxes and radio buttons can be linked to a cell. To do this, right-click on the control and go to *Format Control*; you'll find an option here for *Cell Link*. Set this to a cell of your choice, and the control will store its value in that cell.

Different controls will have different values to store, of course. A checkbox control will simply store `True` or `False`; radio buttons inside a frame will store a number, indicating which button has been selected.

You can then use this cell value in formulae.

2) Use a Group Box Control to group your radio buttons together, allowing controls inside one group to return their values to a single cell while controls in a different group return to a different cell.

In this sample:
[image: Control Groups]

...I created the two groups, `Group Box 6` and `Group Box 10`, first then added the option buttons after. I then right-clicked on `Option Button 7` and set its cell link to `B2`; all the other option buttons in `Group Box 6` automatically picked up the same setting. I then repeated the process with `Option Button 11`, and set its cell link to `B10`. Now when I click one of the option buttons, it puts the appropriate number into those cells.

I've used Form Controls here rather than ActiveX controls; for your purposes, I would recommend sticking with Form Controls. ActiveX controls are a little more powerful, but they work better with VBA than with formulae. For a relatively simple setup, stick with Form Controls.